# Reading an integer into a local variable in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator, spim

How can I read an integer into a local variable in MIPS?

The problem asks me to use the concept of assigning integer variables as local variables. (A question from my text book.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
li $v0, 5              # MARS/SPIM call number 5: read int
syscall                # return value in $v0
move $t0, $v0
```

The value is now in $t0. This will read the integer from the console.

"local variables" in asm can be registers or stack space.

MARS system-call documentation: http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html

Comment: I hope this is what you mean.

Comment: here is the table that holds the `code 5` from `$v0`: http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html